# data structure: pandas dataframe or relational database for my model?

Tags: python, dataframe, relational-database, simulation

I want to build a model which is supposed to calculate the value of a parameter for the receiving process to optimize a warehouse’s capacity.

The parameter makes the decision in the receiving process where a SKU is going to be stored - as a palett in the high-bay racking (more expensive) or as a carton in the automatic carton shelf (less expensive).

The parameter is set based on this data:

Concerning the sum of all SKUs:

- the capacity of the high-bay racking
- the capacity of the carton shelf.

The capacity of the racking and shelf depend on the current inventory level of all SKUs and the volume leaving the storage (because the SKUs are sold).

Concerning the single values for each SKU and each day (20.000 SKUs and 365 days):

- number of products of this specific SKU received per day
- number of products of this specific SKU sold per day
- predicted number of products of this specific SKU to be sold in the x upcoming days
- volume already stored in the automatic carton shelf of this specific SKU

Now, I wonder which data structure I should use in order to import and use the data in my process in Python as the data encompasses four values for 20.000 SKUs and 365 days each.

I thought that I should use the Pandas Dataframe because it is very powerful in building models and visualization. But as the tabular form only has a kind of 2D nature, as I understand, I would not be able to model the data for 20.000 SKUs and all 365 days because this is kind of more 3D.
Therefore, I wonder whether I have to use a relational database, where each of the above mentioned data sets (received volume per SKU, sold volume per SKU,  predicted number to be sold per SKU, volume in carton shelf per SKU) would make up a table.

I found the following set of questions in the answer to one question here, which I feel are important to answer my questions. Here are my answers:

1) Size of data, # of rows, columns, types of columns; are you appending rows, or just columns?

number of rows: 20.000 SKUs

number of columns: if you take separate tables for each data set, than it is 365 columns (=days); if it is one table, than it is 365 * 4 (365 days * received volume per SKU, sold volume per SKU,  predicted number to be sold per SKU, volume in carton shelf per SKU)

types of columns: floats, boolean

As I understand, I am not appending data but I use the data to calculate values for each SKU, and then from the bottom (the detailed data on the SKU) to the top (the sum of all SKUs = capacity, inventory level)

2) What will typical operations look like. E.g. do a query on columns to select a bunch of rows and specific columns, then do an operation (in-memory), create new columns, save these.

sum, subtraction, multiplication, division, bigger than, smaller than, equal to ...

3) Giving a toy example could enable us to offer more specific recommendations.
    Example:

SKU 123456:

- has 200 liters of inventory in carton shelf
- 1000 liters are received today
- 300 liters will be sold today
- predicted sales for x days is 250 liters (should be in carton shelf)

the parameter is set to 600 liters (if the volume of the receiving is higher, it goes in the palett racking, otherwise in the carton shelf)

so you need to store the following volume:

- 200 liters in inventory + 1000 liters received = 1200 of inventory
- 1200 liters - 300 liters sold = 900 of inventory
- 250 liters needed in carton shelf = 650 liters left

as 650 > 600, 250 liters are stored in the carton shelf, the other 650 in the high-bay racking

Overall sum:
inventory high bay racking after the receiving of this SKU is + 650 liters
inventory carton shelf is + 50 liters

If the capacity of the high-bay racking is already full, and +650 liters is not possible, the parameter has to be recalculated, so that the total on this day fits in.

-> the calculation is proceeded for the next 364 days …

4) After that processing, then what do you do? Is step 2 ad hoc, or repeatable?

repeatable, as it needs to be done for every day

5) Input flat files: how many, rough total size in Gb. How are these organized e.g. by records? Does each one contains different fields, or do they have some records per file with all of the fields in each file?

I guess they need to be organized by SKUs and days

6) Do you ever select subsets of rows (records) based on criteria (e.g. select the rows with field A > 5)? and then do something, or do you just select fields A, B, C with all of the records (and then do something)?

yes -> it always checks whether the capacity is met; whether there is a need to put some volume into the carton shelf, …

7) Do you 'work on' all of your columns (in groups), or are there a good proportion that you may only use for reports (e.g. you want to keep the data around, but don't need to pull in that column explicity until final results time)?

I guess, mostly, there are calculations made on the data, so it is not just keeping the data around…

Thank you so much upfront!

Comment: `pandas` provides a three-dimensional data-structure, the [`panel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel). Although, it is not as fully-featured as the `DataFrame` or `Series`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Panel is now deprecated.